# Any help identifying these parts and their purpose

Tags: integrated-circuit, surface-mount

Short: I'd like a manufacturer identified.
Long; I've been tearing apart old electronics and looking at them to see how they work and getting caps, op amps, transistors, small logic circuits and the such off, but I've come across a chip on the board that has me stumped. It's off of an old hughesnet modem board that I was going to strip for the Ethernet jack. I've seen this manufacturer's logo several times in multiple power bricks while I was hunting for toroidal rings, so I think it may be some sort of power company. I was just wondering if anyone has seen this logo before and if so, what company it belongs to. I tried googling sti, 691, 6pi, s9i, etc. No hits. Any help? I'm posting this from my phone so I'll link to the pics. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0em8s.jpg

Comment: Not exactly on topic, but I am facing difficulty in identifying the IC. Searching 1501088-0002LC or 1501088 on google doesn't return anything usefull escept some vendors selling the same SOP20 IC. NO reference to any datasheet or anything. Does anyone know what is this IC supposed to do? Or better find a datasheet?

Answer (score 6):

That's [STMicroelectronics](http://www.st.com/web/en/home.html). They're everywhere.